# Best practices before doing string manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, string

Is there a recommended best practice for checking for NULL and empty (anything else?) before doing string manipulations, in C#? Specifically, I needed to call Replace and Trim on a string, but find that doing that on a NULL string throws. So is there a better format than the following?

tmp = (tmp == null) ? null : tmp.Replace("TOKEN", "").Trim();

Comment: `NULL` (from a database using ADO.NET) is not the same thing as `null` -  if you're using `IDataReader` use `IsDBNull()` and/or check for reference-equality with `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: If you're using C# 6.0 or newer, look into the `?.` operator.

Comment: Depending on your C# version you can use more concise expressions such as `(tmp ?? "").Replace("TOKEN","").Trim();`  or `tmp?.Replace("TOKEN","")?.Trim();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` in .NET 4.0 or later, or `String.IsNullOrEmpty` in .NET 3.x.

```
String temp = ...
if( !String.IsNullOrWhitespace( temp ) ) {
    temp = temp.Replace("TOKEN", "").Trim();
}
```

C# 6.0 adds the `?.` operator, which is "null-safe", it just returns null and skips the rest of the navigation expression:

```
String temp = ...
temp = temp?.Replace("TOKEN", "").Trim();
```

As I remarked in my comment, if you're accessing a database using ADO.NET (`DataSet`, `DataTable`, `IDataReader`, etc) then you should check for `DBNull` which is used to indicate SQL `NULL` values, which are distinct from `null` in C#:

```
using( IDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader() ) {

    while( rdr.Read() ) {

        String value = rdr.IsDBNull( someColumnIndex ) ? null : rdr.GetString( someColumnIndex );
    }
}
```

Or:

```
DataTable table = ...
foreach( DataRow row in table.Rows ) {
    if( row["someColumn"] != DBNull.Value ) {
        String value = (String)row["someColumn"];
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Just something to point is to declare temp with the alias `string temp` and not with the upper case `String`

Comment: @Sxntk `String` and `string` are equivalent. I prefer the Type-name instead of the intrinsic name, it comes down to personal preference. Both are valid.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko No, if `temp` is null then `.Trim()` won't be called, and `String.Replace` never returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I have learnt a lot of great things from all the feedback to this question :)